# working with java JNI GetFieldID and JNI in general

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm not having much luck with JNI at all it seems. I'm waiting for a book I bought to arrive, but for now it's trial-and-error.

I'm using JNI to implement a Lua evaluator. evaluatorNew() just creates a new Evaluator() object, creates a new CPtr() class object as described on Java-side, assigns our Evaluator() object's pointer to the CPtr's 'peer' member, and returns the new CPtr jobject.

```
JNIEXPORT jobject JNICALL Java_com_starlon_libscriptable_UtilsEvaluator_evaluatorNew(
    JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
{
    int foo = 1;
    while(foo);

    Evaluator *eval = new Evaluator();

    jobject obj;
    jclass tempClass;

    tempClass = env->FindClass("com/starlon/libscriptable/CPtr");

    obj = env->AllocObject( tempClass );
    if (obj)
    {
        env->SetLongField( obj, env->GetFieldID( tempClass, "peer", "J" ), (jlong)eval);
    }
    return obj;
}
```

Here's the Java class to hold our pointer. This is what 'env->FindClass()' is calling up.

```
public class CPtr
{
    /* Pointer value of the real C pointer. Use long to be 64-bit safe. */
    private long peer;

    protected long getPeer()
    {
        return peer;
    }

    /* No-args constructor. */
    CPtr() {}

}
```

There is no stack trace to speak of as you can see below.

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0xafd15ca8 in __libc_android_abort ()
   from /home/scott/workspace/StarVisuals/StarVisuals/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
#1  0x00000008 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

Here's a dump from gdb stepping through the JNI function above:

```
0x80805258 in Java_com_starlon_libscriptable_UtilsEvaluator_evaluatorNew (env=0xabd8, 
    clazz=0x40715698) at jni/libscriptable//evaluator.cpp:85
85      while(foo);
Current language:  auto; currently c++
(gdb) set foo = 0
(gdb) s
[New Thread 11226]
[Switching to Thread 11226]
87      Evaluator *eval = new Evaluator();
(gdb) u
92      tempClass = env->FindClass("com/starlon/libscriptable/CPtr");
(gdb) u
94      obj = env->AllocObject( tempClass );
(gdb) u
95      if (obj)
(gdb) s
97          env->SetLongField( obj, env->GetFieldID( tempClass, "peer", "J" ), (jlong)eval);
(gdb) s
_JNIEnv::GetFieldID (this=0xabd8, clazz=0x40715910, name=0x8080a134 "peer", sig=0x8080a13c "J")
    at /opt/android-ndk-r7b/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include/jni.h:708
708     { return functions->GetFieldID(this, clazz, name, sig); }
(gdb) print functions
$1 = (const JNINativeInterface *) 0xaca9dd68
(gdb) print this
$2 = (_JNIEnv * const) 0xabd8
(gdb) print clazz
$3 = (jclass) 0x40715910
(gdb) print name
$4 = 0x8080a134 "peer"
(gdb) print sig
$5 = 0x8080a13c "J"
(gdb) print *functions
$6 = {reserved0 = 0x0, reserved1 = 0x0, reserved2 = 0x0, reserved3 = 0x0, GetVersion = 0xaca43385, 
  DefineClass = 0xaca43355, FindClass = 0xaca4773d, FromReflectedMethod = 0xaca47719, 
  FromReflectedField = 0xaca476f5, ToReflectedMethod = 0xaca476b9, GetSuperclass = 0xaca44801, 
  IsAssignableFrom = 0xaca4450d, ToReflectedField = 0xaca4767d, Throw = 0xaca43331, 
  ThrowNew = 0xaca47655, ExceptionOccurred = 0xaca447b1, ExceptionDescribe = 0xaca4761d, 
  ExceptionClear = 0xaca43315, FatalError = 0xaca44d99, PushLocalFrame = 0xaca475c1, 
  PopLocalFrame = 0xaca47561, NewGlobalRef = 0xaca44ac1, DeleteGlobalRef = 0xaca4502d, 
---Type <return> to continue, or q <return> to quit---q
SetByteFieldQuit
(gdb) print functions->GetFieldID
$7 = (jfieldID (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, const char *, const char *)) 0xaca47435
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0xaca4cd0c in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0xafd15ca8 in __libc_android_abort ()
   from /home/scott/workspace/StarVisuals/StarVisuals/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/libc.so
#1  0x00000008 in ?? ()
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
(gdb) quit
```

Here's line 708 of jni.h:

```
jfieldID GetFieldID(jclass clazz, const char* name, const char* sig)
{ return functions->GetFieldID(this, clazz, name, sig); } // 708
```

Any help? Please let me know if I need to clarify anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AllocObject` allocates but does not construct an object. I suspect `SetLongField` may violently throw up if you call it on an unconstructed object, as you're doing here. Use `NewObject` instead; you'll have to query for the methodid of the no-argument constructor, first.

Comment: Well, it turned out the issue was elsewhere due to the Lua library I'm using tossing an exception due to bad Lua code being passed. It seems that stepping through those JNIEnv* methods (GetFieldID) causes the VM to barf. At any rate, I learned something from you, so here's the upvote. :)

Answer (score 3):

Your code takes a lot for granted. You need to check the result of every, and I do mean *every,* JNI call, by looking for an exception, and aborting if you get one. You mustn't just stack up function calls Lisp-style like that and hope they all return usable values.

Answer (score 0):

You should always run with CheckJNI: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/07/debugging-android-jni-with-checkjni.html

It would have told you that you were calling a JNI function with an exception pending, and aborted cleanly.